# TS7053 (typescript) как избавиться от этой ошибки при обращении к ключам объекта?

Tags: typescript

Есть такой код:

```
interface Obj {
      a: string
      b: string
    }
    
    const obj: Obj = {
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
    }
    
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      obj[key] = `.${value}` // << TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type 
// because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Obj'.  
// No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Obj'.
    })
```

Подскажите, как правильно это написать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для использования переменной типа `string` в качестве ключа, нужно добавить [описание индексатора](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) в интерфейс `[index: string]: string;`

```
interface Obj {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  [index: string]: string;
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAbgOXVIqpDoYG1QATCAD2IsaAXWaUa9AL548CAPYgKyOVlIZsAXlwMSyAORw9AGgZN96Y3ml51EBGAB0EcFQhkAFCswBKBzDlQAKKIABbu7hwA1hAAnkbIAG5wADYArhDC3sgaAHzahF5RscLZyAAGDgAkOElpEJJlyAD0TcgAPG3IACoAygDsAAwArADMpIHJEAC2zmDIwFMADsnACMBgyTHIIXBkRCD6cCAxeshgMYsoeC2MdnCpZCj8i1BuZMAKyjBnFyh6QmxTggjno5ugUA8INwznJ5iBeHwfpd9Oo9A5CNdWgA5WE8fjkYDUEBwMCpV7IADu6xCRGQizgUDgM0gUC+SL+AOopwpu2Q-lS8OUB3OyL0qIcVm8QA)